How to extract this official "cross" for plot marker?
There are many ways of plotting with cross markers. We can simply use x, X and many similar characters. Or define a cross graphic
Cross plot markers
publication-quality-plotmarkers
But they are not offcially offered markers, and some are just cross-like.
Then I realized that in the RootLocusPlot the "official" cross is indeed there.
RootLocusPlot[TransferFunctionModel[{{{k (1 + s)}}, ((-1 + s) s) (16 + 4 s + s^2)}, s], {k, 0, 80}]


My question is how to extract/obtain this cross object so that we can use for other plots.

markers = {"\[Times]", "\[FilledSmallCircle]", "\[SmallCircle]"}; Graphics[  Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 40], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]] & /@ markers].

It is just made with lines:
out = RootLocusPlot[TransferFunctionModel[{{{k (1+s)}},((-1+s) s) (16+4 s+s^2)},s],{k,0,80}] ;
Cases[FullForm[out], Graphics[x__], Infinity]
First[Cases[FullForm[out], Graphics[x__], Infinity]]
Cases[FullForm[out], Inset[x__], Infinity]
FullForm[First[Cases[FullForm[out], Graphics[x__], Infinity]]]
(* Graphics[List[GrayLevel[0],Thickness[0.25`],Line[List[List[0,1],List[1,0]]],Line[List[List[0,0],List[1,1]]]],Rule[ImageSize,List[8.`,Automatic]]] *)


